# How do I forward a cookie using fetch in getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm using Nextjs for my app. On a page, I would like to fetch data from an authenticated API endpoint ('/api/profile').

I have tried the following, with no success:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const { req, res } = ctx
  const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie ?? '')
  const mycookie = cookies[MY_COOKIE] // mycookie exists and is set correctly

  if (mycookie) {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.SERVER_HOST+'/api/profile', {
      credentials: 'same-origin' // I tried with and without this, also tried "include" instead
    })

  ...
```

I have 2 questions:

- Is there a way to avoid having to enter the absolute URL? (I was hoping to simply use '/api/profile', since it's an "internal" api)
- How do I make sure the cookie required to fetch data from /api/profile is forwarded through `fetch`?

N.B: My cookie is `httpOnly`.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I'm allowed to manually forward the cookie through:

```
if (mycookie) {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.SERVER_HOST+'/api/profile', {     
    headers: {
      cookie: mycookie
    }
  })
...
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use get server side props then the recommended way is to process whatever data fetching functions you have directly in getserversideprops.

calling fetch /api is redundant.  what you can do is to extract the function from the api and use it directly in getserversideprops.

what you are doing now is
client -> serverside rendering -> api -> serverside rendering -> client

it can become
client -> serverside rendering -client

Comment: But if we include all of API logic in serverSideGetProps, then why do we need a separate backend server. Wouldn't this highly couple our frontend and backend logic?

Comment: It really depends on what your backend and your app do really. If your app consist of only server side generated pages then yes backend is redundant. But I doubt so, I believe you will have api end points as well.

Comment: Yes I have some other APIs as well which are being used by ajax requests inside the hydrated react components.